# How do I find the working svn directory in Windows 10

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I inherited a VM with various code from a client whose original software engineer passed away. I'm having a hard time finding where all the code is on the drive, but did notice TortoiseSVN installed. That got me thinking, if I can find where the repo is stored on the drive, that may give me a head start!

The problem is, I can't seem to find that location on the drive. `svn info` and any other svn commands I try tell me the directory I'm currently in "is not a working copy". I'm in Windows 10 and it has tortoisesvn installed.

Comment: Why dont you just search for `.svn` folder? Where this hidden folder is located that is the location of your working directory...

Comment: Ahh! Because I didn't know.